# Only shows 4 images from 6!

Tags: graphics, floats, subfig

Hello I have 6 images and output has only 4 images. Here is the codes:
I tried to fix to problem via \clearpage comment to separate the first three. What happened to my other 2 images?
Thank you!!

```
% RECOMMENDED %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\documentclass[graybox]{svmult}

% choose options for [] as required from the list
% in the Reference Guide

\usepackage{mathptmx}       % selects Times Roman as basic font
\usepackage{helvet}         % selects Helvetica as sans-serif font
\usepackage{courier}        % selects Courier as typewriter font
\usepackage{type1cm}        % activate if the above 3 fonts are
                            % not available on your system

\usepackage{epstopdf}       % Converts eps to pdf if your version of 
                            % Tex (or pdflatex) does not support eps

%
\usepackage{makeidx}         % allows index generation
\usepackage{graphicx}        % standard LaTeX graphics tool
                             % when including figure files
\usepackage{multicol}        % used for the two-column index
\usepackage[bottom]{footmisc}% places footnotes at page bottom
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{caption}
%\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\captionsetup{compatibility=false}
\usepackage{placeins}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{romannum}
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{ragged2e} 
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{lscape}


\usepackage[justification=centering]{caption}

% see the list of further useful packages
% in the Reference Guide

\makeindex             % used for the subject index
                       % please use the style svind.ist with
                       % your makeindex program

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[h!]
\begin{subfigure}[h!]{\textwidth}
     \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{lena_image&histogram.jpg}
  \centering
  \label{fig:3_9_2}
    \caption*{Source: Image Databases, Standard Test Images \cite{data_lwpcmphlwj}}
   \caption{Lena Image and Histogram}
 \end{subfigure}
 \begin{subfigure}[h!]{\textwidth}
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{barbara_image&histogram.jpg}
\centering
\label{fig:3_9_5}
\caption*{Source: Public-Domain Test Images for Homeworks and Projects \cite{data_bb}}
\caption{Barbara Image and Histogram} 
\end{subfigure}
\begin{subfigure}[h!]{\linewidth}
 \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{cameraman_image&histogram.jpg}
 \centering
\label{fig:3_9_6}
\caption*{Source: Image Databases, Standard Test Images \cite{data_lwpcmphlwj}}
\caption{Cameraman Image and Histogram}
\end{subfigure}
\clearpage
\begin{subfigure}[h!]{\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{boat_image&histogram.jpg}
\label{fig:3_9_10}
\caption*{Source: Public-Domain Test Images for Homeworks and Projects \cite{data_bb}} 
\caption{Boat Image and Histogram}
\end{subfigure}
\begin{subfigure}[h!]{\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{jetplane_image&histogram.jpg}
\label{fig:3_9_14}
\caption*{Source: Image Databases, Standard Test Images \cite{data_lwpcmphlwj}}
\caption{Jet plane Image and Histogram}
\end{subfigure}
\begin{subfigure}[h!]{\textwidth}\ContinuedFloat
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{mri_image&histogram.jpg}
\label{fig:3_9_16}
\caption*{Source: Northern Arizona University, Gray Scale Images \cite{data_mri}}
\caption{MRI Image and Histogram}
\end{subfigure} 
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I guess that your six images occupy more than the height of the page, so the last two go beyond the page margin.

Comment: exactly. what is your suggestion? how can I fix?

Comment: Rearrange your layout of the six pictures in a 3×2 form would be a good idea.

Comment: Images will be smaller, I need 6x1

Comment: Well, from your response to @egreg’s comment, it’s rather clear that 6×1 simply doesn’t fit into one page. So you either scale down your pictures, or you split them into two 3×1’s (or three 2×1’s). I don’t see any reasons to use the current layout when we know for a fact it is impossible to get everything on one page (unless, you want to create a larger page specifically for these 6 pictures).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**EDIT** Just to be clear, this is not really an answer...

This code show how to manipulate the `subfigure` positions. Of course you may already have an idea for the positionning of your images (6x1) for instance, but if you cannnot put everything in the same page, you lose your audience too... Sometimes it is simply better to split the information (if possible) to be clearer.

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}       
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}


\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[h!]
\centering
\begin{subfigure}[h!]{0.33\textwidth}
    \centering
     \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-a.jpg}
 \end{subfigure}%
\begin{subfigure}[h!]{0.33\textwidth}
    \centering
     \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-b.jpg}
 \end{subfigure}%
 \begin{subfigure}[h!]{0.33\textwidth}
    \centering
     \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-c.jpg}
 \end{subfigure}
 \begin{subfigure}[h!]{0.33\textwidth}
    \centering
     \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-a.jpg}
 \end{subfigure}%
 \begin{subfigure}[h!]{0.33\textwidth}
    \centering
     \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-b.jpg}
 \end{subfigure}%
 \begin{subfigure}[h!]{0.33\textwidth}
    \centering
     \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-c.jpg}
 \end{subfigure} 
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}[h!]
\centering
\begin{subfigure}[h!]{0.5\textwidth}
    \centering
     \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-a.jpg}
 \end{subfigure}%
\begin{subfigure}[h!]{0.5\textwidth}
    \centering
     \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-b.jpg}
 \end{subfigure}
 \begin{subfigure}[h!]{0.5\textwidth}
    \centering
     \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-c.jpg}
 \end{subfigure}%
 \begin{subfigure}[h!]{0.5\textwidth}
    \centering
     \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-a.jpg}
 \end{subfigure}
 \begin{subfigure}[h!]{0.5\textwidth}
    \centering
     \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-b.jpg}
 \end{subfigure}%
 \begin{subfigure}[h!]{0.5\textwidth}
    \centering
     \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-c.jpg}
 \end{subfigure} 
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}[h!]
\centering
\begin{subfigure}[h!]{\textwidth}
    \centering
     \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-a.jpg}
 \end{subfigure}
\begin{subfigure}[h!]{\textwidth}
    \centering
     \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-b.jpg}
 \end{subfigure}
 \begin{subfigure}[h!]{\textwidth}
    \centering
     \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-c.jpg}
 \end{subfigure}%
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

- your images are to big that can be fitted on one page.
- on way, how you use `subfigure` you have two options:

  - reduce their size or
  - divide them into multiple pages, but not on the way as you try (one float cannot be split on two parts)
- for the first case see [BambOo's](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/141947/bamboo) answer
- for the second case you can exploit `\ContinuedFloat` macro from the `\caption` package and manually divide images between to floats:

  ```
  \documentclass[]{article}
  \usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
  \usepackage{caption}
  \usepackage{subcaption}

  \usepackage{lipsum}

  \begin{document}
  \lipsum[11]
      \begin{figure}[b!]
  \setkeys{Gin}{width=\linewidth}
  \begin{subfigure}{\linewidth}
       \includegraphics{lena_image&histogram.jpg}
  \caption*{Source: Image Databases, Standard Test Images \cite{data_lwpcmphlwj}}
  \caption{Lena Image and Histogram}
      \label{fig:3_9_1}
  \end{subfigure}

  \begin{subfigure}{\linewidth}
      \includegraphics{barbara_image&histogram.jpg}
  \caption*{Source: Public-Domain Test Images for Homeworks and Projects \cite{data_bb}}
  \caption{Barbara Image and Histogram}
      \label{fig:3_9_2}
  \end{subfigure}
  \begin{subfigure}{\linewidth}
      \includegraphics{cameraman_image&histogram.jpg}
  \caption*{Source: Image Databases, Standard Test Images \cite{data_lwpcmphlwj}}
  \caption{Cameraman Image and Histogram}
      \label{fig:3_9_6}
  \end{subfigure}
  \caption{common caption}
      \label{fig:3 9}
      \end{figure}
  %
      \begin{figure}[!t]
  \ContinuedFloat                % <---
  \setkeys{Gin}{width=\linewidth}
  \begin{subfigure}{\linewidth}
      \includegraphics{boat_image&histogram.jpg}
  \caption*{Source: Public-Domain Test Images for Homeworks and Projects \cite{data_bb}}
  \caption{Boat Image and Histogram}
      \label{fig:3_9_10}
  \end{subfigure}
  \begin{subfigure}{\linewidth}
      \includegraphics{jetplane_image&histogram.jpg}
  \caption*{Source: Image Databases, Standard Test Images \cite{data_lwpcmphlwj}}
  \caption{Jet plane Image and Histogram}
      \label{fig:3_9_14}
  \end{subfigure}
  \begin{subfigure}{\linewidth}
      \includegraphics{mri_image&histogram.jpg}
  \caption*{Source: Northern Arizona University, Gray Scale Images \cite{data_mri}}
  \caption{MRI Image and Histogram}
  \label{fig:3_9_16}
      \end{subfigure}
  \caption{common caption (cont.)}
      \end{figure}
  ```

[image]
[image]

with keys `Gin` are set width of all images in one float, consequently code id a little bit shorter

**off-topic:**

- labels had to be always after caption and not before
- position options `[!h]` for `subfigure` has no sense. sub figures are always inside float `figure`, with options `t` or `b` is possible vertical align them to top or bottom, if they are two or more in one line
- use of the `\centering` in `subfigure` when width of image in it is equal `\linewidth` also has no sence
- regarding citing sources of images see if use of the `copyrightbox` is acceptable to you:

  ```
  \documentclass[]{article}
  \usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
  \usepackage{caption}
  \usepackage{subcaption}
  \captionsetup[sub]{skip=-6pt}
  \usepackage{copyrightbox}

  \usepackage{lipsum}
  %---------------- show page layout. don't use in a real document!
  \usepackage{showframe}
  \renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.15pt}
  \renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}
  %---------------------------------------------------------------%

  \begin{document}
      \begin{figure}[!b]
  \setkeys{Gin}{width=\linewidth}
  \begin{subfigure}{\linewidth}
  \copyrightbox[b]{\includegraphics{lena_image&histogram.jpg}}{Source: Image Databases, Standard Test Images \cite{data_lwpcmphlwj}}
  \caption{Lena Image and Histogram}
      \label{fig:3_9_1}
  \end{subfigure}

  \bigskip
  \begin{subfigure}{\linewidth}
  \copyrightbox[b]{\includegraphics{barbara_image&histogram.jpg}}{Source: Public-Domain Test Images for Homeworks and Projects \cite{data_bb}}
  \caption{Barbara Image and Histogram}
      \label{fig:3_9_2}
  \end{subfigure}

  \bigskip
  \begin{subfigure}{\linewidth}
  \copyrightbox[b]{\includegraphics{cameraman_image&histogram.jpg}}{Source: Image Databases, Standard Test Images \cite{data_lwpcmphlwj}}
  \caption{Cameraman Image and Histogram}
      \label{fig:3_9_6}
  \end{subfigure}
  \caption{common caption}
      \label{fig:3 9}
      \end{figure}
  \lipsum[1]
  \end{document}
  ```

[image]

(red lines indicate text borders).

in above example is also changed `subcaption` setup.